# Notation in Abelian Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, notation, abelian-groups

I'm reading the book *Abelian Groups and Representations of Finite Partially Ordered Sets* by D. Arnold, and when he proves one result he says:

> "Let X = $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{11}]$, the subring of Q generated by $1/11$ and Y = $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{31}]$. Define $G = X \oplus Y +\Bbb Z(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5})$ and $H = X \oplus Y +\Bbb Z(\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5})$ subgroups of $\mathbb{Q} \oplus \mathbb{Q}$. Then both $G$ and $H$ are almost completely decomposable groups of rank $2$."

How should I interpret $\mathbb{Z}(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5})$? I don't know if the use of *parentheses* indicate other stuff than *square brackets*, as in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{11}].$

Comment: Perhaps elements on the form $(n/5,n/5)$?

Comment: Usually, $K(x,y)$ means the field of fractions of $K[x,y]$.

Comment: I suspect $\mathbb{Z}(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5})$ means the subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}\oplus\mathbb{Q}$ generated by the element $(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5})$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang But $\mathbb Z$ is not a field (and the field of fraction would simply be $\mathbb Q$. The interpretation from the other comment is correct.